# ImageSource Binding Slow for Normal Sized Image using C# and XAML in WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, imagesource

I'm still fairly new to MVVM and data binding. I have a GUI that changes an image depending on what the user selects in a combobox. The problem is there is a momentary lag when the image needs to change. The lag freezes the GUI and then the image appears and things work normally. I'd like the GUI to not freeze even if the image loads slow.

The image is not a thumbnail like others have asked about and there are solutions posted out there. It's .png with the largest one being about 17K. It seems like this should be fast given the size of the image.

I've tried using a different thread, but I think the problem is in the Image.Source. I'm not sure how to run xaml on a separate thread but that was my brute force attempt at fixing this.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here's the xaml:

```
<!-- Image -->
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
       Grid.RowSpan="10"
       Margin="40,40,40,0"
       Width="Auto"
        >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
        Height="Auto"
        Source="{Binding Path=ProfileImage}"
        Stretch="UniformToFill"
        Width="Auto"
       />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
        Content="{Binding Path=Profile}"
        Height="{Binding Path=ProfileCaptionHeight}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
        />
</Grid>
```

Here's the bound property:

```
public string ProfileImage
{
    get
    {
        if (this.ProfileImageShown)
        {
            return _profileImage;
        }
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        _profileImage = value;

        if (value != null)
        {
            this.ProfileImageShown = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ProfileImageShown = false;
        }
        base.OnPropertyChanged("ProfileImage");
    }
}
```

where _profileImage is the full path of the image.

Comment: What are the pixel demissions of the images you are loading in ? If they are very large images (width * height). This may be the cause.

Comment: Is the largest image really 17K? That is nothing, and it should be loaded without any noticeable delay. There is possibly some other thing wrong with your application. As a note, in your `ProfileImage` property, the getter and setter are inconsistent, i.e. the getter doesn't return what you passed as argument to the setter. That is bad practice and should be avoided. Imagine what happened if you called `this.ProfileImage = this.ProfileImage;`

Comment: @steveybrown: the pixel dimensions are 729x444

Comment: @ Clemens: I was thinking the same thing, 17K is nothing. So what could be causing the delay? Thanks for pointing out the getter/setter inconsistency. I hadn't thought about that scenario. Little by little I'll get better at this!

Comment: When looking at the largest image properties in Windows Explorer, it says the image is 16.4KB but size on disk is 20.0KB. I wonder how that's possible if the total pixel count is 323,676? Either way it's a pretty small image and should load so fast it isn't noticeable.

Comment: Also getting this delay. There is no CPU usage during the delay. Delay time is random. Giving me a very sluggish interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding IsAsync=true to your binding.  That should stop it locking your UI at the very least.  As said above, it should be pretty fast anyway, so there might be something else going on.

```
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                Height="Auto"
                Source="{Binding Path=ProfileImage, IsAsync=True}"
                Stretch="UniformToFill"
                Width="Auto"
               />
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip. You're right, there must be something else going on because I didn't notice any change in the lag. Once I figure it out, I'll let you know.

Comment: With this the user at least doesn't have to wait. But the images still appear with huge delay and can cause misinformation in some context.